# localhost is not working in tomcat server

Tags: windows, tomcat, operating-system, system-administration, server-administration

I have modified hosts file and uncomment the 127.0.01  localhost and stop&start 'DNS client' services also, But still it is not working and throwing same error.

> Cannot Connect                                                                      The proxy could not connect to the destination in time.
>   [image]
>   Please find the attached screenshot for reference.

Answer (score 0):

localhost is by default an IPv6 address since Windows Vista ( ::1 )
It's not 127.0.0.1 anymore.

You have to handle IPv6's local addresses, or type 127.0.0.1 directly to force the use of IPv4, or change the hosts file in etc/drivers to reconfigure Windows' default behavior.

Now your problem is linked to the use of a proxy server. If you go to the Internet parameters, you may see there's a proxy configured. Add 127.0.0.1 as an exclusion.

Edit: I also remember that McAffee uses the port 8080 for its own antivirus service. Your application is probably conflicting the AV. You'll have to use another port or uninstall McAffee.